# Make sed replace ONLY exact strings

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, preg-match

i have a css file like the following:

```
    #layout.one-column  #menu-secondary{background: #3c3c3c; height: 20px; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS'; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px; padding: 10px;}     
    #layout.one-column  #menu-secondary a {color: #FFF; text-decoration: none;}
    #layout.one-column  #menu-secondary ul {}   
    #layout.one-column  #menu-secondary ul li {display: block; height: 30px; float: left; margin: 0 20px 0 0;}  
    .ofr h2 {font-size: 17px; height: 35px; margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;}  
    .ofr h2 a {color: #2a2a2a; text-decoration: none;}      
    #layout.one-column  #menu-secondary ul li.active {background: url(../img/selected.gif) no-repeat bottom center;}
    #layout.one-column  #menu-secondary ul li a {display: block; float: left; padding: 0 10px;}     
    #layout.one-column  #menu-secondary ul li a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
```

As you can see every line in its beginning has tabs/couple blank spaces and the string starts with .whatever/#whatever. I've coded a litle script wich at a point runs:

```
find css/myCSS.css -name "*.css" -type f -exec sed -i "s/\<$pattern\>/$replacer/g" {} \;
```

where `$pattern` could be `#layout` and `$replacer` could be `#LAYOUT`. What i would like to do, and obviusly i'm doing it in the wrong way is to replace `#layout` by `#LAYOUT` if the strings are

- equal (`blank spaces/tabs before and after the $pattern`)
- equal (`blank spaces/tabs just before the $pattern`) followed by `dot` plus whatever (`#pattern.whatever`)
- equal (`blank spaces/tabs just before the $pattern`) followed by `#` plus whatever (`#pattern#whatever`)
- like `#whatever.pattern` or #whatever#pattern (`blank spaces/tabs just before the #whatever and after #pattern`).

I hope i made it now, cristal clear :)

Here are some examples, in every line #pattern or .pattern should get replaced:

```
#pattern     <- blank spaces/tabs before and after the string  
#pattern.bar <- blank spaces/tabs before #pattern  and after .bar  
.pattern#bar <- blank spaces/tabs before .pattern  and after #bar  
#foo.pattern <- blank spaces/tabs before #foo and after .pattern  
.foo#pattern <- blank spaces/tabs before .foo and after #pattern  
.pattern     <- blank spaces/tabs before and after the string
```

I've been trying to do it using sed but i can't get through and thought i could be "easy" for someone whos' working daily with sed. Thanks again :)

Comment: What shall `\<` mean, and what do you consider a word boundary, if #menu or menu-foo aren't considered to match menu? Only whitespace? What's about `he cried: "menu!"`?

Comment: the examples are abit strange. do you mean #menu-foo should not be replaced by #MENU-foo, and #menu won't be replaced by #MENU? i don't see how #menu-foo would be replaced by #MENU, or #menu by menu?? if the former, then \b would not work..

Comment: The spaces are there because then stackoverflow thinks it's html code and hides it. The thing is i would a word to get replaced only if the string is equal but find public/assets/css/myCSS.css -name "*.css" -type f -exec sed -i "s/\b#menu\b/#MENU/g" {} \; is not doing the job. The idea is to replace #menu but not #menu-foo, and do it even if the text has blank spaces or tabs before #menu.

Comment: There is a preview, and there is a page describing how to format your text and code, to identify code as code. I meanwhile edited your question, but somebody else already inserted the blanks, which is contraproductive in text, formatted as code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i think it's now a bit clearer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewritten based on question rewrite. Warning, some quoting games are played herein:

```
pattern="layout"
replace="FOO"

sed 's/\([ \t#.]\)'"$pattern"'\([ \t#.]\)/\1'"$replace"'\2/g'  << EXAMPLE

 #layout  #layout.whatever #layout#whatever
 #whatever.layout #whatever#layout
 .layout .layout.whatever .layout#whatever
EXAMPLE
```

produces

```
 #FOO  #FOO.whatever #FOO#whatever
 #whatever.FOO #whatever#layout
 .FOO .FOO.whatever .FOO#whatever
```

Comment: I don't know why, but didn't you insert the blanks in the question? They weren't there when I first edited the question.

Comment: @user, no that was the original poster in edit #3, the one before I got my hands into it.

Comment: Hm. But in a code block, you don't need the blanks - he must have seen it!

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks a lot for the answer.  I'm gonna try to explain better as the blank space thing really confused people here :)  I have a css code like this:  #foo  #foo-bar  #foo.bar  .foo  .foo-bar  .bar #foo  I would like, using sed if possible, to give sed a patter and needle to search for an then make sed replace only for the exact word. i mean, i would like to tell sed to only replace patter #foo with replacer #FOO, then #foo-bar and other things like won't get replaced.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what a was looking for. To make it also replace layout by FOO in #whatever#layout and also in #layout{ how should i proceed? Thx again :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redefine word-boundaries to your needs, you need to enumerate them. One approach is, to grab the boundary-pattern and append it in the end:

```
echo "well #menu not #menu-foo #menu" | sed -r 's/#menu([ \t\n\r.!?,]|$)/#MENU\1/g'
well #MENU not #menu-foo #MENU
```

The `|$` is to grab the end of file/end of input case.

I still don't know the role of the leading #, but I guess you can apply the idea so far, if you need something like \1MENU\2 for the first delimiter pattern.

#### update 28.07, 23:45:

- equal (blank/tab before and after the $pattern)
  `[ \t]pattern[ \t]`
- equal (blank/tab just before the $pattern) followed by dot plus whatever (#pattern.whatever)
  `[ \t]pattern.[^ \t]` an exhaustive description of 'whatever' would be better. Additional dots, is - allowed - how do we recognize that 'whatever' ended? Whitespace?
- equal (blank/tab just before the $pattern) followed by # plus whatever (#pattern#whatever)
  `[ \t]pattern#[^ \t]` okay, that's the same as above, just hash instead of dot.
- like #whatever.pattern or #whatever#pattern (blank/tab just before the #whatever and after #pattern).
  `[ \t]#[^ \t].pattern[ \t]` or
  `[ \t]#[^ \t]#pattern[ \t]`

No. 2 and 3 is nearly the same. If we mean A or B, we can simply form a group [#.]. Inside the group, we don't need to mask the dot, because a dot as a joker wouldn't make any sense in a group.

No. 2 and 3 combined is therefore

```
[ \t]pattern[#.][^ \t][ \t]
```

But! You don't do anything with 'whatever'. Whatever it is, it isn't changed. So we add # and . just to the list of delimiters (blank and tab) and return them (or blank or tab), whatever they are:

```
[ \t]pattern([#. \t])
```

A simple test:

```
echo "well #menu not #menu-false #menu.dot #menu#hash" \
| sed -r 's/[ \t]#menu([#. \t])/ #MENU\1/g' 
well #MENU not #menu-false #MENU.dot #MENU#hash
```

This would modify the thing in front of #Menu, be it blank or tab, always to blank. We could capture it too, if wanted.

```
| sed -r 's/([ \t])#menu([#. \t])/\1#MENU\2/g'
```

But what's about the last rule, number 4, where 'whatever' is leading 'pattern'? We can combine dot and hash:

```
[ \t]#[^ \t][.#]menu[ \t]
```

Combining this case into our regex would allow #foo#pattern#bar. That's getting complicated. We better start a fresh, new command:

```
s/([ \t]#[^ \t]+[.#])menu[ \t]/\1MENU /g'
```

which can be appended with ';' after the previous one:

```
| sed -r 's/[ \t]#menu([#. \t])/ #MENU\1/g;s/([ \t]#[^ \t]+[.#])menu[ \t]/\1MENU /g'
```

So I guess I solved your 4 rules, but the example at the top only addresses two of them. And your attempt includes again `\<` and `\>` which is only confusing.

Here my selfmade example, including a case for rule 4:

```
echo "well #bar.menu and #foo#menu #menu not #menu-false #menu.dot #menu#hash" \
| sed -r 's/[ \t]#menu([#. \t])/ #MENU\1/g;s/([ \t]#[^ \t]+[#.])menu[ \t]/\1MENU /g'

well #bar.MENU and #foo#MENU #MENU not #menu-false #MENU.dot #MENU#hash
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks a lot for the answer. I'm gonna try to explain better as the blank space thing really confused people here :)  I have a css code like this:  #foo  #foo-bar  #foo.bar  .foo  .foo-bar  .bar #foo    I would like, using sed if possible, to give sed a patter and needle to search for an then make sed replace only for the exact word. i mean, i would like to tell sed to only replace patter #foo with replacer #FOO, then #foo-bar and other things like won't get replaced.  Thanks again!

Comment: So did you understand my hint about building a group, and does it work, or doesn't it? What is in front of the #foo? And instead of saying 'Thanks', you should upvote helpful posts, and mark the best one as 'accepted'.

Comment: your final example takes `[ \t]` and replaces it with a space ` `. You might be destroying the indenting/layout of the file by doing that. If that matters he could capture and replace as in my example. Also, your example changes both .menu and #menu, a feature he may not expect.

Comment: `a)` I pointed that out at the beginning: `This would modify the thing in front of #Menu, be it blank or tab, always to blank. We could capture it too, if wanted.` Yes - in the later examples, I don't repeat the hint and don't show the alternative - it is already a long answer. `b)` His 6 examples show .pattern and #pattern in the 3rd higlighted block at the end of the question (line 1 and 6).

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 2**

OK, you need to match whole words that start with a `#` or a `.` and are a valid CSS identifier, and then may end with a CSS chain or whitespace.  And they may be at the end of a CSS chain as well?

```
sed -i "s/\(\s+|[#.][a-z_][a-z0-9_-]*\)#pattern\(\s+|[#.:]\)/\1#PATTERN\2/"
```

That is ugly and has everything spelled out. I checked the CSS spec to make sure I had the pattern right for selector IDENTs. There is a `:` in the terminal group because of pseudo-selectors.

**OLDER STUFF**

`\b` won't work for you (because you consider #menu-foo to be a single item and \b sees it as four things `# menu - foo`.)

You need to be clearer about what you consider a "word break" to be before we can help you. At minimum you might try your sed like this if whitespace breaks are what you consider enough:

```
sed -i "s/\(\s\)#menu\(\s\)/\1#MENU\2/"
```

Alternately, you are going to have to specify what a word break consists of. Rather than \s you might need `\(^|[\s"']\)` for the beginning and something real ugly for the end condition.

Based on your comment, if each token you care about is between HTML tags then you could do something like the following. Take the `-i` out of the sed line if you don't want case-insensitivity. At this point, my only question would be if there are also line-breaks in your data. Is all the HTML on one text-line?

```
sed -i "s/>#menu</>#MENU</"
```

or, fancier and including possible line breaks:

```
sed -i "s/\(^|>\)#menu\($|<\)/\1#MENU\2/"
```

We may need sample data to get beyond this...

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks a lot for the answer. I'm gonna try to explain better as the blank space thing really confused people here :) <br/> I have a css code like this:<br/>#foo<br/>#foo-bar<br/>#foo.bar<br/>.foo<br/>.foo-bar<br/>.bar #foo<br/><br/> I would like, using sed if possible, to give sed a patter and needle to search for an then make sed replace only for the exact word. i mean, i would like to tell sed to only replace patter #foo with replacer #FOO, then #foo-bar and other things like won't get replaced.<br/> Thanks again!

Comment: That's still pretty confusing. maybe you can edit your post to add sample data?